# Problem with ridgid bodies entering a box collider from the side

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am making a 3D tetris type puzzle game and I have put in a series of tall colliers with no rigid bodies or mesh renders These are supposed to tell where blocks are on the X/Z plane. When the block enters one of the blocks from the top, it works like a charm, but whenever a collider is entered from the side, the collision detection does not work.
My collision detection looks like this,

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(!filled)
    {
        filled = true;
        Control.topfill++;
    }
}
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if(filled)
    {
        filled = false;
        Control.topfill--;
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, is your tetris game *continuous*? If not so, using rigid body would be a not good idea...

Comment: Never mind guys, I'm retarded, I figured it out. It was working fine, but the subtraction statement was supposed to be in an else.